# Why won't my text show in HTML?

Tags: html, text

I am having a problem because my text won't show in HTML. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<em>Emphasized text</em><br>
<strong>Strong text<script><br>
<code>A piece of computer code</code><br>
<samp>Sample output from a computer program</samp><br>
<kbd>Keyboard input</kbd><br>
<var>Variable</var>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the `head`. Your browser might not render the page without it given its a required tag. Besides that, it should work.

Answer (score 6):

You have an extraneous `<script>` tag.  Change the fifth line to this:

```
<strong>Strong text</strong><br>
```

I suspect what is happening is that your browser is attempting to parse everything which comes after the `<script>` tag as an actual JavaScript.  But since the tag never closes it gives up and dies.  Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to have a look at the console.  There may be errors there.

I just tried to open your HTML file in Chrome, and this is what I saw:

*Emphasized text*
**Strong text**

This is consistent with the browser not rendering anything which comes after the `<script>` tag because parsing failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for instance;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Texts</title>
</head>

<body>
<em>Emphasized text</em><br>
<strong>Strong text</strong><br>
<code>A piece of computer code</code><br>
<samp>Sample output from a computer program</samp><br>
<kbd>Keyboard input</kbd><br>
<var>Variable</var>

</body>
</html>
```

It is not advised to skip the head element because that would be the place where you keep all descriptions and metainformation of your HTML document.